# Can I pass the dynamic values to my select query fields

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot

Can I map the dynamic values to my select query fields using Java, Oracle DB and Spring Boot?

Example:

```
select field1, field2, ?, ?, feild5 
from table 
where field6 = ?
```

I will get the corresponding field values from the query parameter. Also whenever I try to load the SQL query from my properties files and execute, I end-up up with the below error.

```
"message": "PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use bind parameter for column names in `SELECT` statement. That would make the query unpredictable and prevent the benefit of catching query plan between prepared SQL statements.